# Using SOAP with WSDL in Android

Tags: android, soap, wsdl

I used to work with hard coded data, now I got a `Web Service WSDL` that returns `SOAP objects`.

Following `WSDL` instruction, I created a `Class` with the right fields and extracting it by those fields.

But In the instruction of using this `Web Service` it says to use a simple SOAP codegen to generate client classes based on the WSDL.

What is that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you can use a tool in order to generate your Web Service client classes.  That tool generates the Java classes based on the WSDL service definition.

For instance, you can check http://www.wsdl2code.com/
There you simply submit the WSDL and then download the generated source files.